# Moved existing system into new case. Now no signal to monitor

Tags: display, motherboard

One of the fans went bad on my old cooler master case so I ordered a new Gigabyte case.  After transferring the system to the new case I am now getting no signal to the monitor.

Steps I've taken to fix with no success:

1. Tried different DVI adapter.
2. Switched pci-e slots.
3. Switched in a different video card.
4. Re-seated the ram.
5. I even tried some silly gimmick thing of unplugging the power cord and holding the power button for 30 seconds.

I'm at a loss as to what the problem might be, but I fear the mobo might have been damaged in the transfer.  Everything was working great before the switch (other than the broken fan on the old case.)

Does anyone have any ideas that doesn't involve me replacing the motherboard?  (wishful thinking)

Comment: Does the system have a built in output?

Comment: No it does not.  The mobo I have does not have integrated graphics or any form of output.

Answer (score 1):

Did your new case come with a different power supply? 
If so, was the power supply modular?

There is no standard printout for modular power supplies. I've seen people reuse the cables on a new power supply, killing the motherboard because the pinout is different.

Are there motherboard standoffs still in the case? Not all holes are used. Make sure nothing is grounding out on the back of the board.

Did you connect the 4 pin cpu power cable?

Remove variables one by one. Try running the computer outside of the case, ect...

Comment: The case I bought was rather bare bones.  I'm using the same power supply that I was in the old case.  I'll check the mobo to see if its' grounding out, hadn't even thought of that.

Comment: The CPU cable is connected.  I moved the mobo out of the case and ran it without and still had the same problem.  No signal to monitor.  I'm afraid that the mobo is bad.

Comment: reseat the cpu, reseat the ram, try a different ps, different video card, if the motherboard has onboard video, try it. Reset the cmos, remove all other peripherals.

Comment: Just about the only thing I haven't tried is reseating the CPU.  I guess that's my last thing to do before I throw in the towel.